$_POST not set after submit
Why is $_POST not set after submit ?
I'm using WAMPSERVER (x64) up to date.
Thank you for your help.
<!-- index.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST))
        print_r($_POST); // Result: 'Array ( )'
    ?>
</body>
</html>


I can't reproduce your problem, so please check the network tab in the F12 tool to see what data is sent exactly.

The issue with your code is that you are checking isset($_POST) instead of checking if the specific form field is set. The $_POST superglobal itself will always be set; you should check for the specific values submitted.
Here's the corrected code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    // Check if the form has been submitted and the 'fname' field is set
    if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>

Key Changes:
Check Specific Field: Instead of isset($_POST), use isset($_POST['fname']) to check if the form field was submitted.
Output Condition: The print_r($_POST); will now execute only if the form is submitted.

It looks like your form is missing a name attribute for the submit button
. Without this, the $_POST array won't be populated when the form is submitted
. Try adding a name attribute to your submit button like this:
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>


_"Without this, the $POST array won't be populated when the form is submitted" - yes, it will be. With the values of the fields that actually had a name. So here there would be an entry for the fname, just none for the submit button.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    
    if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
        print_r($_POST);
    } 
    ?>
</body>
</html>

If fname is set, it means the form has been submitted, and $_POST data will be printed.


I copy pasted your code but unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Thanks for trying out the code! I'm sorry to hear that it didn't work for you. Since it works on my side, let's troubleshoot to find the issue
change your file name

Please note that the file name index.php might not be acceptable in your setup or configuration. Try changing the file name to something else (e.g., form.php) and update the form's action accordingly. Let me know if that resolves the issue!

The issue with your code is that you are checking is set ($_POST) instead of checking if the specific form field is set.
The $_POST superglobal itself will always be set; you should check for the specific values submitted.
Here's the corrected code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    // Check if the form has been submitted and the 'fname' field is set
    if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>

Key Changes:
Check Specific Field: Instead of isset($_POST), use isset($_POST['fname']) to check if the form field was submitted.
Output Condition: The print_r($_POST); will now execute only if the form is submitted.
